# Different templates for each category level

Tags: theme-development, templates, taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I'm looking for a solution to dynamically create different templates for each category level.

Category

--Category

---Category

----Category

I thought of something to get the taxonomy current level ID, to use a function like below, but I did not find a solution.

I have not found anything that returns me level or a unique ID for each level in a taxonomy

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
echo $term->cat_level_id;


switch ($current_level_id) {
                case 'level_1':
                get_template_part( 'taxonomy-content-level_1',);
                break;
                case 'level_2':
                get_template_part( 'taxonomy-content-level_2',);
                break;
                case 'level_3':
                get_template_part( 'taxonomy-content-level_3',);
                break;
                case 'level_4':
                get_template_part( 'taxonomy-content-level_4' );
                break;
            }
```

I know that wordpress understands taxonomy-custom-slug.php, but it's not something I can use because it's not feasible to create templates since there are many categories / sub.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some time to think about this issue and I was able to put together a clean solution.

Below is my piece of code explained.

This worked well for me.

```
//Search taxonomy current category
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
//Search taxonomy current parents category
$level = get_category_parents( $term->term_id, true, ',' );
//print_r( $levels );
//$str = 'test, test, test, test,,';
$level_count = substr_count($level, ',');
switch ($level_count) {
  case 1:
  echo "Level 1";
  get_template_part( 'taxonomy-custom', 'level-1' );
  break;
  case 2:
  echo "Level 2";
  get_template_part( 'taxonomy-custom', 'level-2' );
  break;
  case 3:
  echo "Level 3";
  get_template_part( 'taxonomy-custom', 'level-3' );
  break;
  case 4:
  echo "Level 4";
  get_template_part( 'taxonomy-custom', 'level-4' );
  break;
  default:
  echo "Level others";
  get_template_part( 'taxonomy-custom', 'levels' );
}
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know of a method already implementing this, a simple approach could be to count the amount of (grand)parents like so:

```
function get_level($id=NULL, $taxonomy='') {
   if ( ! $id) {
     $id = get_queried_object_id();
   }

   $term = get_term($id, $taxonomy, OBJECT);
   if ($term === NULL)
     return 0;

   if ($term->parent == 0)
     return 1;

   return get_level($term->parent, $taxonomy) + 1;
 }
```

Which will return 1 for each term without a parent, 2 for "first level", etc.

You can use this directly in `get_template_part()`. In the example  `$hierarchical_taxonomies` is an array of taxonomies you want to use these special templates for.

```
$hierarchical_taxonomies = array('post_tag', 'my_tax');
if (in_array(get_query_var('term'), $hierarchical_taxonomies)) {
  get_template_part('taxonomy/level', get_level(NULL, get_query_var('term')));
}
```

This will try to load taxonomy/level-1.php, taxonomy/level-2.php, .. Make sure these files exist!

Comment: Thanks Kero for your answer, somehow it works, but for my use I got something different, below I left my piece of solution.

Thank you